# how to properly initialize an object in angular5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to create a questionnaire service using dynamic form approach.
So I have question-base then I have question-textbox,question-dropdwon etc on top of it.

Then I decided to create a questionnaire object that contains an array of questions and information like ID, poster etc.

However when I called add() function in question.service.ts it says questionnaireobj is not defined.

I guess my question is did I successfully make an questionnaireobj instance in questionnaireObj.ts? Or did I refer to it wrongly in question.service.ts?

question-base.ts

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  order: number;
  controlType: string;

  constructor(options: {
      value?: T,
      key?: string,
      label?: string,
      required?: boolean,
      order?: number,
      controlType?: string
    } = {}) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.key = options.key || '';
    this.label = options.label || '';
    this.required = !!options.required;
    this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
    this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
  }
}
```

question-textbox.ts

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class TextboxQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'textbox';
  type: string;

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
    this.type = options['type'] || '';
  }
}
```

question.service.ts

```
// this is where form consumes external data

import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';

import { DropdownQuestion } from './question-dropdown';
import { QuestionBase }     from './question-base';
import { TextboxQuestion }  from './question-textbox';
import { QuestionnaireObj } from './questionnaireObj';


@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {

  // Todo: get from a remote source of question metadata
  // Todo: make asynchronous
  // const newQuestion = new TextboxQuestion() {
// constructor(){}



  add(){

    let newQuestion: QuestionBase<any>[] = [

      new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'yes',
        label: 'Bravery Rating',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        order: 3
      })
    ]

    console.log("newQuestion is" + newQuestion);
    // QuestionService.questionList.append(newQuestion);
    console.log(questionnaireobj);


  }


  getQuestions() {

    let questions: QuestionBase<any>[] = [

      new DropdownQuestion({
        key: 'brave',
        label: 'Bravery Rating',
        options: [
          {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
          {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
          {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
          {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
        ],
        order: 3
      }),

      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'firstName',
        label: 'First name',
        value: 'Bombasto',
        required: true,
        order: 1
      }),

      new TextboxQuestion({
        key: 'emailAddress',
        label: 'Email',
        type: 'email',
        order: 2
      })
    ];

    return questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);
    // console.log(questions);

  }
}
```

questionnaireObj.ts

```
import { DropdownQuestion } from './question-dropdown';
import { QuestionBase }     from './question-base';
import { TextboxQuestion }  from './question-textbox';
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class QuestionnaireObj {

// public questionnaireId?: number;
// public questionList?: QuestionBase<any>[];


// declare the fields and init
constructor(public questionnaireId?:number, public questionList?: QuestionBase<any>[]) { }



let questionnaireobj = new QuestionnaireObj();

questionnaireobj.questionnaireId = 1;
questionnaireobj.questionList = [];

}
```

Comment: Read the error message. Carefully. You haven't posted it (which, to me, means that you don't even think the message could be useful), but I guess it says that the variable `questionnaireobj` is not defined, at the line `console.log(questionnaireobj);` of question.service.ts. This has nothing to do with Angular. You're just trying to use a variable that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

questionnaireObj.ts

```
import {DropdownQuestion} from './question-dropdown';
import {QuestionBase} from './question-base';
import {TextboxQuestion} from './question-textbox';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class QuestionnaireObj {

  questionnaireId: number = 1;
  questionList: QuestionBase<any>[] = [];

  constructor() {
  }

}
```

It still somehow unclear to me about what you want to do. You said "when I called add() function in question.service.ts it says questionnaireobj is not defined." but there is no instance of questionnaireobj inside question.service.ts file.

Comment: Thanks! l thought I could use the instance created in questionnaireObj.ts in question.service.ts. However if I create the instance in question.service.ts it could probably work.